# jquery cloned button action not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, web2py

i have a table with add/remove buttons, those buttons add and remove rows from the table, the buttons are also added with each new row

here what i have as html

```
<table>
<tr>
   <th>catalogue</th>
   <th>date</th>
   <th>add</th>
   <th>remove</th>
</tr>
<- target row ->
<tr id="cat_row">
   <td>something</td>
   <td>something</td>
   <td><input id="Add" type="button" value="Add" /></td>
   <td><input id="Remove" type="button" value="Remove" /></td>
</tr>
</- target row ->
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#Add").click(function() {
         $('#cat_row').after('<- target row with ->'); // this is only a notation to prevent repeatation
         id++;
});

$("#Remove").click(function() {
         $('#cat_'+id+'_row').remove();
         id--;
});
```

Please note that after each addation of a new row the `id` is also changed for example here after clicking the button "Add" **1 time**

```
<table>
<tr>
   <th>catalogue</th>
   <th>date</th>
   <th>add</th>
   <th>remove</th>
</tr>
<tr id="cat_row">
   <td>something</td>
   <td>something</td>
   <td><input id="Add" type="button" value="Add" /></td>
   <td><input id="Remove" type="button" value="Remove" /></td>
</tr>
<tr id="cat_1_row">
   <td>something</td>
   <td>something</td>
   <td><input id="Add" type="button" value="Add" /></td>
   <td><input id="Remove" type="button" value="Remove" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

now the *new added Buttons* has no actions i must always click on the **original buttons** - add/remove

after this i want to make the **Remove Button** removes **ONLY** the row where it is clicked on
for example if i click the button in row 2, row 2 will be deleted

---

**Info:
I use web2py 2.2.1 with python 2.7 with the last version of jQuery**

Answer (score 3):

You can't have two buttons with the same `id` (you're using duplicates for both "Add" and "Remove"). [`id` values **must** be unique on the page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#the-id-attribute).

You might look at using a class instead, and also look at event delegation. For instance, assuming this is the *only* table on your page (if not, just make the selector more specific), if you change your buttons to have classes "add-btn" and "remove-btn" instead of `id` values, then you can use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```
$("table").delegate(".add-btn", "click", function() {
    // An add button was pressed, you can find out which
    // row like this:
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
});
```

...and similarly for the `.remove-btn` button.

Alternately, some prefer to use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) (note the order of arguments is slightly different):

```
$("table").on("click", ".add-btn", function() {
    // An add button was pressed, you can find out which
    // row like this:
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
});
```

Which you use is currently a matter of style. I prefer `delegate` for clarity, but the jQuery team love to hyper-overload their functions. So far they haven't deprecated `delegate`, though they do call it "superceded."

Comment: @IsaakWahb: Good deal! Don't forget to "accept" the answer if it sorted things out for you.

Comment: the problem there is here 2 accepted answers for 2 questions answered from different persons :D
i voted for both answers

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be better instead of:

```
$('#cat_'+id+_row').remove();
```

Do this in your onclick event:

```
$(this).parent().parent().remove();
```

Comment: $(this).parent().parent().after('...') works perfectly too! thanks

Comment: Well in this case $(this).parent().parent() gets your tr tag so you can do whatever you want with it.